# What is OUTER UNION and why is it partially compatible

Tags: terminology, database-theory, relational-algebra

I am trying to understand how a `OUTER UNION` $∪^✳$ works, and why it is only partially compatible.

I am aware this operation was created to take union of tuples from two relations if the relation are not type compatible (which I understand).

Examples of this operation will be great!

Comment: what is the difference between this (outer union) and full outer join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two flavors of outer union: with and without `NULL`s. Google search readily exibits [an example](http://www.databasteknik.se/webbkursen/relalg-lecture/) for `NULL`s version. The cleaner version of relational algebra desn't allow `NULL`s, and outer union is defined via De Morgan's law:

$ X \bigcup Y = \overline {\overline X \Join \overline Y} $

Date&Darwen call this operation [$\blacktriangleleft OR \blacktriangleright$](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/APPXA.pdf).

Given

```
R = [A B]
     1 2
     3 4
```

and

```
S = [B C]
     4 5
     6 7
```

both outer join variants agree that the result projected to common column `B` should be `{2,4,6}`. This is what is called *inner union* -- [alternative way](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0807/0807.3795.pdf) of generalizing standard relational algebra union operator. Now the problem is finding values of attributes `A` and `C`. Next, we match the values of the "middle column" with attributes `A` and `C` trying to leverage information in the relations R and S. In case of value `B=2` we don't have matching value of `C`. Likewise, for `B=6` we don't have matching value of `A`. Therefore, D&D $\blacktriangleleft OR \blacktriangleright$ operator fills the blanks in

```
[A B C]
 1 2
 3 4 5
   6 7
```

with all the values from corresponding domain, while the `NULL` version just blurts `NULL`s.

Comment: I've already looked at the site, is it possible for you to give me a detailed explanation of what is going on there please as the problem is me understanding it.

Comment: what is the difference between this (outer union) and full outer join?